# PHP Code Sniffer shows warning in PhpStorm but not in CLI

Tags: phpstorm, phpcs

I have a little function in a class:

```php
/**
 * @return float|int
 */
private function getPrice()
{
    return rand(1000, 1000000) / 10;
}
```

In PhpStorm I am getting a warning by `phpcs`.

> Missing function's return type declaration

But when I am running the `phpcs` from command line by:

```
phpcs --standard=PSR12 ./
```

I am getting no error message about this return type.

I've tried to search it in ruleset, but there is only a comment about this:

```
<!-- When you have a return type declaration present, there MUST be one space after the colon followed by the type declaration. The colon and declaration MUST be on the same line as the argument list cl
<!-- checked by PSR12.Functions.ReturnTypeDeclaration -->
```

But I did not see any rule for this.

Can somebody help me, how can I turn it on from the `ruleset.xml` or from command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Missing function's return type declaration` is a PhpStorm inspection; it doesn't come from PHP_CodeSniffer, which [doesn't have this feature yet](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/issues/2063).

Comment: So, then where this is come from? PHPStorm PSR12 settings, or php-cs-fixer? Does PHP Cs fixer gaves wantings?

Comment: You can find the inspection in PhpStorm at `Settings | Editor | Inspections PHP | Type compatibility | Missing return type declaration`